# How do I read different sitecore fields in the mail?

Tags: exm, sitecore-forms

Each property detail page has a `Request a viewing` button which opens a form. The ask is, on the click of the submit button of this form an email with property title, URL, image(Sitecore fields) should be triggered to the user. When the form page opens up from the property detail page, I am passing the property GUID in the query string for reading different fields of that property. How do I get these fields in the mail? These values will be different for each property. 
I am able to read the form fields in the mail using the tokens. How do I `read the Sitecore fields`?

Comment: Is there any criteria that which image field value will be send to which user?

Comment: @swati The image of the property for which the user clicks on "Request a viewing" button.

Comment: You can create custom field which will read query string guid and convert into image type.Then you can access that custom value like other field

Comment: Not able to whip up an answer right now, but using a Custom Submit Action that uses the EXM Client API to Send a Message, allows you to pass in tokens that can be replaced in the email using token dollar sign notation ($tokenname$) https://sitecorehacker.com/2018/12/21/managing-the-unsubscribe-part-5/

Comment: Also, re-reading your question... is your question how to get custom data into emails?  Or how to get a Sitecore Item up via a GUID in the query string?